# Вызвать функцию другой программы

Tags: c#

Есть две программы Server и Client. Client знает о функциях сервера и хочет их вызвать.

Код ниже это просто пример того, что хотелось бы получить. У меня три вопроса: Можно ли запаковать вызов функции вместе с аргументами, затем передать и выполнить.

Код клиента:

```
class Client{

    public Server.MyType UserFnc(string data, int data2){ //Функция вызываемая пользователем

        object packedFnc = Server.UsefullFnc(data, data2); //Запакуем вызов функции которая есть на сервере

        var result = (Server.MyType)CallFnc(obj); //Получим результат

        return result; //Вернем результат пользователю
    }

    public object CallFnc(object obj){ // Функция отправки "вызова функции" серверу

        MemoryMappedFile.Write(obj); //записали obj в память и ждем
        //Wait for ReturnFnc
        object result = MemoryMappedFile.Read(); // дождались ответа, считываем и возвращаем результат

        return result;
    }
}
```

Код сервера

```
class Server{

    public void ReturnFnc{

        var cFnc = MemoryMappedFile.Read(); //Читаем вызов ф-ии

        var result = cFnc.invoke(); //выполняем UsefullFnc, получаем результат

        MemoryMappedFile.Write(result); //отправляем рузельтат
    }

    public MyType UsefullFnc(string data, int data2){ //Делает нечто полезное
            var result = new MyType(data, data2);
        return result;  
    }       
}
```

Comment: Да, прочитайте про IPC каналы.

Comment: Можно просто строчкой записать имя функции, и передать вместе с сериализованными аргументами. А на сервере уже это выполнить как команду. По типу удалённого интерпретатора.

Comment: _вызов функции которая есть на сервере_ - т. е. она вам заранее известна. Вот и вызывайте её напрямую, без всяких обёрток. ЗЫ: посмотрите в сторону WCF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Сервер это библиотека выполняемая lua -интерпретатором. Чтобы выполнять ее функции нужно получить адрес стека который передается во время экспорта библиотеки. Я пробовал этот адрес передать клиенту, но в итоге выходит ошибка "Попытка доступа к защищенной памяти"

Comment: @D.Stark Сейчас так и делаю, но функций много все с разными аргументами. Страх что будет если все это описывать.

Comment: Не адрес функции в памяти имеется в виду, а адрес в пути (URL).

Comment: @D.Stark Не сразу понял что Вы имели ввиду, теперь понял. Спасибо вопрос решен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы имеете ввиду клиент должен получить что-то вроде смещение программы + смещение стека?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ по ссылке [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381904/call-method-in-object-with-string)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new object(); // Replace here with your object 

        var type = obj.GetType();
        var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);

        // Invoke the method here
        methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
    }
}
```